# Is there a possibility of generating a 6 digit unique random number every time with xdmp:random() or some other way in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I tried using `xdmp:random(999999)` but it sometimes generates a 5 digit value and sometimes a 6 digit value - Is there any way of getting the every time unique 6 digit value?

Comment: Are six-digit numbers with a leading zero acceptable?

Comment: No leading zero is not acceptable as per the requirement.Thanks but this worked - format-number(xdmp:random(999999), '000000').

Comment: I asked because that call on format-number() will sometimes produce a number with a leading zero.

Comment: You're concerned about getting unique values but wanting to use random. I think those requirements conflict. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MichaelKay - Ok I thought you meant that padding every random number with leading zeroes in case the count of/length of random number does not matches the required count of 6.

Comment: @DaveCassel - I am basically working to figure out that in the application where I am involved will be generating an OTP on every new login of any user.So I tried making it unique with xdmp:random() but since the resultant value is quite large as per user's perspective so I wanted to precise that every unique random value to a length of 6.

Comment: Okay. You should expect to get collisions sometimes and plan for that. The only way to avoid that is to use a UUID (sem:uuid()). Even if you add a couple more digits, it might still happen, so your application should keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If leading zeroes don’t work, make sure your base value is 100,000 and go up to 999,999.

`xdmp:random(899999) + 100000`

Comment: Thanks for the above !! Will figure this out in case leading zeroes don't work.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest is to pad with zeros using `fn:format-number`:

```
format-number(xdmp:random(999999), '000000')
```

Alternatively, you could also look at `sem:uuid-string`, which gives better random results with a fixed string-length.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks much!! The above worked well .I hope this will not return any duplicate entries.

Comment: You said in comments that a six-digit number containing a leading zero is not acceptable: ie. you're concerned with the range being 100000 to 999999, not with the format being six digits. If that's the case then this solution looks wrong.

Comment: That comment came after posting this answer, but if it is true, use hunterhackers solution instead.

Comment: Note though that collisions (e.g. duplicates) cannot be prevented this way, not even with sem:uuid-string, however unlikely (and with sem:uuid, changes really are rare). I created this ml-unique library a while ago, which compares a few alternatives: https://github.com/grtjn/ml-unique#how-it-works

Comment: @grtjn - Thanks for sharing this ml-unique library!!Yes will approach the hunterhackers solution .